# How to calculate the average of rows between a start index and end index of a column in a dataframe in Spark using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with a column having float type values. I am trying to find the average of values between row 11 to row 20. Please note, I am not trying any sort of moving average. I tried using partition window like so -

```
var avgClose= avg(priceDF("Close")).over(partitionWindow.rowsBetween(11,20))
```

It returns an 'org.apache.spark.sql.Column' result. I don't know how to view `avgClose`.

I am new to Spark and Scala. Appreciate your help in getting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign an increasing id to your table. Then you can do an average between the ids.

```
val df =  Seq(20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1).toDF("val1")
val dfWithId = df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
val avgClose= dfWithId.filter($"id" >= 11 && $"id" <= 20).agg(avg("val1"))
avgClose.show()
```

result:

```
+---------+
|avg(val1)|
+---------+
|      5.0|
+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you Zack ! That worked perfectly. I am new to Spark and didn't know about monotonically_increasing_id(). It's going be helpful in several ways going forward. Cheers !

Comment: No problem at all @AkdeEdge! Please accept this as the answer if you would be so kind.